# Adding object to array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have problem with adding object to array of pointers of objects. Here's a function I'll be talking about:

```
void add(Car **cars, int number) {
    Car *fresh = new Car;
    fresh = new Car;
    cout << "Enter the name of your car." << endl;
    cin >> fresh->name;
    cout << "Enter max velocity of your car." << endl;
    cin >> fresh->maxV;
    cout << "Enter weight of your car." << endl;
    cin >> fresh->weight;
    delete[number-1] cars;
    cars[number-1] = fresh; // here's something wrong
}
```

I allocated memory for `number`-of cars in array of pointers `**cars` and then I try to add new object `fresh` at the end of array, firstly deleting memory in last index of array of pointers of objects and then passing reference to last index of array, but I get an error. I tried to solve problem myself, by I didn't found similiar topic in web. I hope somebody will guide me how to solve it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? `new Car` seems like invalid syntax.

Comment: I get error when I try to pass reference of 'fresh' to 'number-1' index of 'cars' array in last line of function.

Comment: Did you `malloc` cars before you passed it in as a pointer?

Comment: The compiler should print an error for `delete[number-1]` that it is not valid (and for `Cars *fresh = new Car;` because `Cars` and `Car` do not match), and would not compile as of that. Why do you assume that you get an error for `cars[number-1] = fresh`? Anyway in c++ you should use standard containers like `std::list`, `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Your compiler lets you `delete[number-1] cars;` ?   And I'm pretty sure you are not done with `cars` at that point, so why are you returning what it points to to the memory pool?

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake 'fresh' is of type Car.

Comment: What I basically want to do is to add a new object to the very last index of array of pointers to objects `cars`. I might be wrong with implementation, so  if somebody would give me a hint on how to fix it or how to do it correctly I would be thankful.

Comment: Unless you are really wed to the idea of using a C style array, @Genarito  was trying to direct you to a better way, like using `std::vector` as a container to hold your Car objects

Answer (score 0):

No need of delete statement. The code would be like this if you already allocated memory for 'cars'.

```
Car *fresh = new Car;
cars[number-1] = fresh; //number here should be index starting from 1 not number of Car objects
```

The cars would be initialised like following before calling method add().

```
Car ** cars = new (Car *)[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to delete the allocated memory for `cars[number-1]` use

```
delete cars[number-1];
```

Otherwise, you don't need to call `new` twice to allocate `fresh`.
So, the following should work

```
void add(Car **cars, int number) {
  Car *fresh = new Car;

  cout << "Enter the name of your car." << endl;
  cin >> fresh->name;

  delete cars[number-1];
  cars[number-1] = fresh; 
}
```

and you need to make sure that `number` is the size of your cars array.

Answer (score -1):

It could be better if you use

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
```

So you could do the next:

```
cars.push_back(fresh);
```

And that's all. Sorry about my english

Comment: Though things might get more complex if a `Car` is not a PlainOldData type object